# Change display of an element based upon criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like users to be able to distinguish if they've voted for something (by bolding it) or haven't voted for it yet (not bolded).

For example:

```
       Voted For Post     Unvoted for
Votes:  77 ↑ ↓             12 ↑ ↓
```

Here is how my database is set up:

### intro

Contains messages

```
    message_id    intro            user_id      up_vote
     10            Voted For Post   5            77
     11            Unvoted for      5            12
```

### voting

Contains votes

```
    Voting_id     message_id_fk      user_id
     18             10               5   
     19             10               3
```

### users

Contains user names

```
    first_name    user_id
     BOB           5
```

I don't know how to properly query the database then make the proper `if statement` that will distinguish between voted for and unvoted for posts.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intro
         INNER JOIN users ON intro.user_id = users.user_id
         ORDER BY `up` DESC ");

echo $row['first_name'] . " " .  $row['intro'];

if( ??? ) {
  echo "<strong>" . $row['up_vote'] . "</strong>";
} else {
  echo $row['up_vote'];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm stuck on something similiar- good question :D

Comment: So you are wanting to bold the values in the far-right column (up_vote)?

Comment: Yes, only when a user has up voted them.

Comment: What value will be in the column if there isn't an upvote?  A '0' or null/blank?

Comment: OK.  I was thinking if it was null or blank you just set your class to  bold that field.  Then it would only be bold if it was upvoted.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Are you wanting bolded when someone clicks an upvote action, or bolded when the user has an up_vote count greater than 0?  To bold it greater than 0, just use basic PHP logic to check the value of up_vote in the loop, and wrap <strong> tags around the value.

Comment: I want it to be bolded if the user has it upvoted

Comment: @njk You are correct, and I suspect the only way people will stop using `mysql_*` is when it is removed. If history is any guide, there will be a terrific howl from the folks who ignored the warnings.

Comment: @uneducatedguy something you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/7BcF2/

Comment: @wirey someone else just asked the same question :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572815/change-color-and-number-onclick-of-a-div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left join the Voting table and check if any corresponding items were found:

```
SELECT intro.message_id, intro.intro, intro.user_id, intro.up_vote,
    IF(Voting.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS has_voted
FROM intro
INNER JOIN users ON intro.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN Voting ON Voting.message_id_fk=intro.message_id
    AND Voting.user_id = 5
ORDER BY `up` DESC
```

Then in PHP:

```
if($row['has_voted'){
    echo "<strong>".$row['up_vote']."</strong>";
}else {
    echo $row['up_vote'];
}
```

Some explanations:

- Columns from a `LEFT JOIN`ed table are `NULL` if no matching rows were found
- `IF()` is a function that returns the second parameter if the first parameter evaluates to true, otherwise returns the third parameter. As a function it can be easily used in the `SELECT` clause
- I replaced `SELECT *` by explicit selection of the needed columns, which is considered a best practise and in this case necessary because of ambiguous column names
- Of course you will have to replace the literal `5` with your current user id. Use prepared statements or concatenate the query like this: `"...Voting.user_id = " . intval($current_user_id) . "..."`

Comment: Hm, I think it's almost working you just neglected the first_name

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked that. I guess you can figure out how to select more columns?

Comment: Without knowing what the error says: no. Well, maybe... your table is called "users", so obviously "user" won't work. It should be: `SELECT users.first_name, intro.message_id, ...`

Comment: I can't give bounty for 24 hours, I'm sorry.

Comment: It means your query was invalid. MySQL will tell you more: to debug the query, place `if (!$sql) die(mysql_error());` before the call to mysql_fetch_array.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to have only the posts where the current logged in user (say the user having user_id = 3) had upvoted them, you could use this query:

```
SELECT u.first_name,
       m.message_id,
       m.message,
       m.up_vote,
       v.Voting_id
FROM Users u,
     Messages m
LEFT JOIN Voting v ON v.message_id_fk = m.message_id AND v.user_id = 3
WHERE u.user_id = m.user_id;
```

In your code, use the proper procedure to replace the 3 above with the user_id from the currently logged in user.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a962/8/0)

If you execute this query, you'll notice that I've added a column to the result: voting_id.

If the user **upvoted** this post, it will show the **id** of the vote.
If the user **did not** upvote, it will show **NULL** value.

You can then check this field in your code for *not null* and you're done!

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to work.... If i create an additional column "Voting_id" within my sql table that contains the "Voting_id" in it, It will only bold user 5's vote and not the rest of the users who have upvoted it.

Comment: So, just to clarify, an example: you are logged in as "Suzy" (having user_id 3) and you want to display all messages in a list. The posts "Suzy" has upvoted have a **bold** number of votes and the other ones plain?

Comment: Yes, You want to display all the messages in the list that Suzy has upvoted- if you're suzy.