# Change color and number onclick of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to change a color and number of a html element on click of a div. 
For example, when you click `up-arrow` the number changes from 4 to 5 and the color 
changes as well.

```
initial state
```

## ↑ 4  ↓

```
upvoted
```

### ↑ *5*  ↓

```
down voted
```

### ↑ *3*  ↓

here's what I have so far.
I know how to change the color of a div on click, however I don't know how to change the color of a div from an onclick of a different div. And then on top of that add the +1 or -1.

http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/23/

note- user:[uneducatedguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402910/uneducatedguy) just asked this same question however he deleted it because people were making fun of him since he called it a fiddle in stead of a jsfiddle.

Comment: I was hoping for this question to come back as I had already prepared a jsfiddle answer. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to reinvent the SO? ;)

Comment: Too bad we can't ask user:uneducatedguy. I'm also curious what he wants to do with this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) this is really simple:

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow-up" data-bind="click: num.upvote.bind(num)"></div>
<h5 data-bind="text: num.value, css: { pink: num.changed }">3</h5>
<div class="arrow-down" data-bind="click: num.downvote.bind(num)"></div>
```

javaScript:

```
function Num(value) {
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
    this.changed = ko.observable(false);
}

Num.prototype.upvote = function() {
    this.value(this.value()+1);
    this.changed(true);
}

Num.prototype.downvote = function() {
    this.value(this.value()-1);
    this.changed(true);
}

var model = {
        num: new Num(1),
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

See it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/UvKsz/

With protection against multiple votes:

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/UvKsz/1/

Comment: Adding extra logic (e.g. only one up and/or downvote allowed, resetting the color, etc.) is really simple but since the original question did not state any further requirements I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm assuming whoever asked this question is trying to spoof some sort of basic ajax effect... You should modify your code so you can only up vote once and down vote once.

Comment: I just added a second revision of the jsfiddle which only allows to vote once. I just hope anyone finds this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$('#clickDIV').click(function() {
  var x = $('#zielDIV').text() +1;
  $('#zielDIV').html(x);
});
```

Comment: I think you have to parse to int the text before the sum and also you can pass the text as argument for text function ;)